# what is mathematical description of parabola produced by intersection of two evolving circles?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

[this video](https://www.facebook.com/PhysicistTv/videos/vb.119326601418561/1088321494519062/?type=2&theater) makes one wonder about what is mathematical description of parabola produced by intersection of two evolving circles?
is this description having a temporal dimension makes it relavant physics and not math?

To help clarify the question a bit, having looked at the video, let me rephrase it, in a way that the OP will, I hope, approve:

Given two distinct points $P$ and $Q$, you can build a circle $C_t$ of radius $t$ about $P$ and a circle of $C'_t$ of radius $t + a$ about $Q$ for some constant $a$. For large enough values of $t$, these intersect, and if we consider such intersections, for all $t$, they seem to all lie on one hyperbola. Can you mathematically show that this collection of intersections forms a hyperbola, and describe the hyperbola in terms of $P, Q,$ and $a$?

Comment: It's a hyperbola (or at least one half of a hyperbola, as shown), not a parabola. But asking "how would you describe this?" is a perfectly good math question, yes.

Comment: I've added a rephrasing to your question; can you confirm that I got the ideas right, please?

Comment: OP, have you looked at parametric representation of curves, where a "traditional"$y=F(x)$ function is represented as two functions of a new parameter, $t$, viz. $x=f(t), y=g(t)$? Historically, the original motivation for this representation was indeed physical, hence $t$ for time, but it is now just as much firmly part of applied maths. You might be interested in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own rephrasing of the question:

Suppose that $X$ is a point of $C_t \cap C'_t$. Then because it's on $C_t$, the distance from $X$ to $P$ is $t$ --- the radius of $C_t$ is $t$, after all. Similarly, the distance from $X$ to $Q$ is $t + a$. The *difference* between these two distances is $(t+a) - t = a$, i.e., it's independent of $t$.

Now suppose instead that $X$ is a point whose distance to $Q$ is $a$ greater than its distance to $Q$. If we let $t$ be the distance from $X$ to $P$, then we see that $X$ lies on $C_t$, and similarly that it lies on $C'_t$.

In summary: the points of $C_t \cap C'_t$, for all possible values of $t$, are exactly the points for which the distance to $Q$ is $a$ greater than the distance to $P$.

Since a hyperbola is typically described by saying that it's the set of points where the difference of the distances to two points is a constant, you can see that the set I've described is exactly one part of a hyperbola. (The other "arc" consists of points where the distance to $P$ minus the distance to $Q$ is $a$.)

So: what looks like a hyperbola in the video really *is* a hyperbola, and it's the one defined by 
$$
\{ x \mid d(X, Q) - d(X, P) = a \}
$$
where $a$ is the size of the circle around $Q$ at the time that the circle around $P$ starts growing.